# Qt - Cross Compiling

Tags: qt, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling, configure

I am doing a cross compiling [mips] of Qt and Qt based applications.
Two developement machines; one 64bit and other 32bit, are used for this purpose. 
Generally Qt related libraries and binaries are cross compiled in 64 bit machine. Qt based application, is cross compiled in 32bit machine.

With this setup, there is a small problem with usage of moc/qmake/qrc etc; These are compiled on 64bit machine and cannot run on the 32bit machine.

One shortcut method, is to change the mkspec [Pass -m32 instead of -m64 in linux-g++-64 ]. 
This way issue is resolved.

What I wanted to know is, if we can configure Qt itself to use linux-g++-32 instead of 64, for compilation of qmake/moc etc binaries.

Comment: Try with `-platform linux-g++-32 -xplatform your-mips-mkspec'

Comment: Thanks Frank, it worked. :). if you put it in answer, I can select the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `-platform linux-g++-32 -xplatform your-mips-mkspec`